# How to find integer values and compare them then transfer the main files?

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, fortran, string-comparison

I have some output files (5000 files) of .log which are the results of QM computations. Inside each file there are two special lines indicate the number of electrons and orbitals, like this below as an example (with exact spaces as in output files):

```
    Number of electrons               =        9
    Number of orbitals                =       13
```

I thought about a script (bash or Fortran), as a solution to this problem, which grep these two lines (at same time) and get the corresponding integer values (9 and 13, for instance), compare them and finds the difference between two values, and finally, list them in a new text file with the corresponding filenames.
I would really appreciate any help given.

Comment: Only one instance of these 2 lines are present in the entire file?

Comment: @Amir What have you tried so far? This is a relatively simple `awk` problem. Please look at some documentation or online tutorials rather than asking without trying anything.

Comment: To get you started, try `awk -F= '/^Number/ {print $2}' file` which will give you the values you want to subtract. Then you could save them in variables and do the subtraction or do the difference in `awk` itself. Then it is a matter of redirecting to an output file.

Comment: @Inian Yes in each file there are only these two special lines, and no similar lines present

Comment: @VarunM I actually tried some grep -w and grep -Eo with "and" & "or" conditions commands. But first of all, non of them gave me the exact corresponding integer values, second, the command doesn't work alone and that's why I am thinking about writing a script which includes all the commands. Sorry I am totally beginner with scripting and commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am posting an attempt in `GNU Awk`, and have tested it in that only.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.log
do
    awk -F'=[[:blank:]]*' '/Number of/{printf "%s%s",$2,(NR%2?" ":RS)}' "$file" | awk 'function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v} {print abs($1-$2)}' >> output_"$file"
done
```

The reason I split the `AWK` logic to two was to reduce the complexity in doing it in single huge command. The first part is for extracting the numbers from your log file in a columnar format and second for getting their absolute value.

I will break-down the `AWK` logic:-

- `-F'=[[:blank:]]*'` is a mult0 character delimiter logic including `=` and one or more instances of `[[:blank:]]` whitespace characters.
- `'/Number of/{printf "%s%s",$2,(NR%2?" ":RS)}'` searches for lines starting with `Number of` and prints it in a columnar fashion, i.e. as `9 13` from your sample file.
- The second part is self-explanatory. I have written a function to get the absolute value from the two returned values and print it.
- Each output is saved in a file named `output_`, for you to process it further.

Run the script from your command line as `bash script.sh`, where `script.sh` is the name containing the above lines.

Update:-

In case if you are interested in negative values too i.e. without the absolute function, change the `awk` statement to

```
awk -F'=[[:blank:]]*' '/Number of/{printf "%s%s",$2,(NR%2?" ":RS)}' "$file" | awk '{print ($1-$2)}' >> output_"$file"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Inian for your kind help! The code works perfect. But there is one more question; in the case that I don't want the absolute value of subtraction of the two values gained (negative values are also so important), then what changes should be applied to the code?

Comment: Yeeeeaaaaaahhh it works. Thank you indeed, I really appreciate your helps, thank you so much!

Comment: @Amir: Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Bad way to do it (but it will work)-

```
while read file
do
    first=$(awk -F= '/^Number/ {print $2}' "$file" | head -1) 
    second=$(awk -F= '/^Number/ {print $2}' "$file" | tail -1) 

    if [ "$first" -gt "$second" ] 
    then 
        echo $(("$first" - "$second")) 
    else 
        echo $(("$second"  - "$first"))
    fi > "$file"_answer ; 
done < list_of_files
```

This method picks up the values (in the `awk` one liner and compares them.

It then subtracts them to give you one value which it saves in the file called "$file"_answer. i.e. the initial file name with '_answer' as a suffix to the name.

You may need to tweak this code to fit your purposes exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much Varun M for your kind help and answer! Unfortunately, the code didn't work for me, but I really appreciate your help. I even tried to change it to eliminate the IF statements and just keep the line;  echo $(("$first" - "$second")), but it didn't work again. But thank you so much again!